# Calling an action through a link that is not in routes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

The project is a portfolio with works, and I intend to order them by category.

I am trying to make a filter for my projects by category, in which by clicking a button which relates to the before nominated category should, display this projects first;

The html is the following

```
    </div>

    <h1 id=title>Projects</h1>
        <div id="post_wrap" class="skiny_wrap">
            <% @projects.each do |project1|  %>
            <% if project1.category ==  @choice %>
                <div class="post">
                    <h2 class="name"><%= project1.name %> </h2>
                    <p class="description"><%= project1.description %> </p>

                    <% if project1.has_photo? %>
                         <%= link_to("example_url") do %>
                                 <div class="img_container" style="background-image: url(/photo_store/<%=project1.id%>.<%=project1.extension%>)"></div>
                         <% end %>
                    <%else%>
                            <p> there is nothing here </p>

                    <%end%>


                    <p class="category"><%= project1.category %> </p>
                    <p class="date"><%= project1.created_at.strftime('%A, %B %d') %> </p>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <%end%>
                <% end %>

            <% @projects.each do |project|  %>
                <% unless project.category == @choice %>
                <div class="post">
                    <h2 class="name"><%= project.name %> </h2>
                    <p class="description"><%= project.description %> </p>

                    <% if project.has_photo? %>
                       <%= link_to("example_url") do %>
                           <div class="img_container" style="background-image: url(/photo_store/<%=project.id%>.<%=project.extension%>)"></div>
                       <% end %>
                    <%else%>
                        <p> theres nothing here </p>
                    <%end%>


                    <p class="category"><%= project.category %> </p>
                    <p class="date"><%= project.created_at.strftime('%A, %B %d') %> </p>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <%end%>
                <% end %>
        </div>
```

What I pretend is using this

```
            <%= link_to image_tag("logo.png",:alt => "logoIndex1"), {:controller => "projects", :action => "index1"} %>
```

Changing the value of choice, with the following action of my controller

```
def index1
    @choice="gato"
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

Comment: link_to helper won't work if the url is not recognisable eg the url is not defined in routes.rb.

Comment: what do you recommend then? should I make it a button perhaps?

Comment: You have two options really: 1.  Frontend solution ie output everything and use js or css to control filtering, 2. Backend solution(which you intend to do) and it requires setting up routes, controller action etc. I reckon option 1 suits you better here(based on the given info anyway)

Comment: I have been so far 3 days with this , I think your solution is a bit vague could you pleaseguide me out a little more? you see, if I use front and have more than one pagination, I can only filter but the first page, however from the back I could filter it completely so could you throw more light into the fornt possibility for it interests me greatly? thank you very much

Comment: what have you tried?what's the results?what's the errors?If you paste your work in progress into the question then we can go from there